# Is DATABASEDOTCOM Ruby gem affected by SFDC dropping SSL3.0 support?

Tags: rest-api, integration, security, ruby

SFDC recently stated they will not support SSL3.0 any longer.  Notification goes on to say currently supported browsers all use TLS by default so the users are safe.  My concern is an external ruby app I inherited which uses the DATABASEDOTCOM gem.  [The github page](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom) explains authentication is via username and password/security token. So, I'd like to confirm our external integration is unaffected by SFDC dropping SSL3.0 support.

Comment: For future reference, I posted a way to check the HTTPS security protocol with tcpdump & wireshark at:  http://scotthung.wordpress.com/2014/11/10/how-to-check-the-https-security-protocol-used/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have a recent version of OpenSSL, then Ruby automatically uses TLS by default, so the gem should still operate without modification. I took a peek at that gem plus net/https to verify that the behavior should be unaffected.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I confirmed our version of OpenSSL supports both SSLv3 and TLS so I should be covered.  I never looked in depth at Ruby (this is an inherited app) and spent way too much time trying to figure what protocol got chosen - Only to decide to wait one more day to see if things broke.  I did learn that Net::htp must be configured to check the SSL certificates though, so that's worth something!